# How can I pass parameters to second level super class

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to understand inheritence and have some problems to understand.

```
public class SiteTemplate extends SiteTemplateMethods

    public SiteTemplate(String country, String language, HttpServletRequest request){
        super();


    }   

public class SiteTemplateMethods extends Resources

public class Resources extends PropertyFiles
```

1) class `PropertyFiles` all methods will be accessible from classes `Resources`, `SiteTemplateMethods` and `SiteTemplate`. Is that right?

2) `super();` in `SiteTemplate` constructor will pass all parameters to `SiteTemplateMethods` but these parameters are not required here in class `SiteTemplateMethods` how can I get the parameters of the `SiteTemplate` class to second level super class `Resource` class?

Best regards

Comment: 1. Yes (except private methods). 2. You have to pass them through `SiteTemplateMethods`'s constructor. There are other options like `Resources` having an abstract provider method that you implement in subclass, but that would require to make `SiteTemplateMethods` abstract or it would have to implement those methods.

Comment: it means first I have to write same constructor with parameters as in `Resource` class and then will use super() keyword. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you would just call `super(country, language, request);` instead of `super();`. By the way, `super();` on its own is redundant - it happens automatically.

Comment: can you please give example in code as this will be most clear to me. I will also learn about abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) class `PropertyFiles` all methods will be accessible from classes `Resources`, `SiteTemplateMethods` and `SiteTemplate`. Is that right?

No, it is not right.  All `public` and `protected` members of `PropertyFiles` will be accessible to descendant classes, including `Resources`, `SiteTemplateMethods`, and `SiteTemplate`, but the `private` methods of `PropertyFiles` will not be accessible to subclasses.  Package-private methods will be accessible to descendant classes only if they are in the same package as `Resources`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

There are additional limitations on accessing methods that have been overridden (as first noted by @Gergely).

> 2) `super();` in SiteTemplate constructor will pass all parameters to `SiteTemplateMethods`

No, it won't.  `super()` with no arguments invokes the no-argument constructor of the immediate superclass, passing no arguments to it.  If the immediate superclass does not have an accessible no-arg constructor then the invocation is invalid.

To invoke a different constructor, i.e. as one that accepts arguments, you must invoke `super()` with a corresponding argument list.

> but these parameters are not required here in class `SiteTemplateMethods` how can I get the parameters of the `SiteTemplate` class to second level super class `Resource` class?

If `SiteTemplateMethods` has an accessible constructor that will pass the arguments on to an accessible (to it) constructor of `Resource`, then you can use a corresponding `super()` invocation (with arguments) at the beginning of `SiteTemplate`'s constructor.  Otherwise, `SiteTemplate`'s constructor will need to apply the parameters directly, in a manner appropriate to class `Resource`, such as by invoking property setter methods.

Comment: My basic question last part is if superclass public methods can be accessible to all child class then child class parameters should be accessible with super keyword to all super classes either its 2nd or 3rd or n level classes. Is that possible?

Comment: I have no idea what makes you think that such a thing should be possible.  Generally speaking, classes know *nothing* about their subclasses.  Moreover, in no event does any constructor or method have access to the parameters or local variables of the constructor or method that invokes it.  You can pass parameters (explicitly) to a constructor, including via `super()`, but that affects only the constructor directly being invoked, not (directly) any other constructor or method it invokes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's declare some methods.

```
public class Resources extends PropertyFiles{
     public Resources(String country,String language){
          super();
          //...
     }
     public void a(){
          //...
     }
     public void b(){
          //...
     }
     public void c(){
          //...
     }
}
public class SiteTemplateMethods extends Resources{
     public SiteTemplateMethods(){
          super("foo","bar");
          //...
     }
     public void a(){
          //...
     }
     public void b(){
          super.b();//This will call the superclass's method
          //...
     }
}
```

1) In `SiteTemplate`, you can access `c()` from `Resources` but not `a()` and `b()`, because they were overridden by `SiteTemplateMethods`. Calling `a()` will call the `a()` method in `SiteTemplateMethods` instead. If you have an instance of `SiteTemplate` then you can't call the `a()` method of `Resources`. The `b()` method in `SiteTemplateMethods` however, calls the superclass method, and executes additional code after it.

2) In constructor calls you can only access constructors declared by the class that your class directly extends. In the given example You can't call `super(String country,String language)` in `SiteTemplate`, unless `SiteTemplateMethods` declares the following:

```
public SiteTemplateMethods(String country,String language){
     super(country,language);
     //...
}
```

Also note that methods with different parameters are treated as two different methods. so `a(String str)` does not override `a()`. However, this is not true, if the overriding method is fully applicable for the arguments of the previous method. So `a(Object o)` does override `a(String str)`.